# How to include both a parsed response and original response headers in fetch errors

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

I have the following promise chain:

```
return fetch(request)
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => ({ response: json }))
  .catch(error => ({ error }))
```

Where `checkstatus()` checks if the request was successful, and returns an error if it wasn't. This error will be caught and returned. But, the problem is that I want to add the both `response.statusText` and the results of `response.json()` to the error. The problem is that when I parse it I lose the original response in the chain since I have to return `response.json()` because it's a promise.

This is what checkstatus does currently:

```
const checkStatus = response => {
  if (response.ok) return response

  const error = new Error('Response is not ok')

  // this works because the response hasn't been parsed yet
  if (response.statusText) error.message = response.statusText

  // an error response from our api will include errors, but these are
  // not available here since response.json() hasn't been called
  if (response.errors) error.errors = response.errors

  throw error
}

export default checkStatus
```

How do I return an error with `error.message = response.statusText` and `error.errors = response.json().errors`?

Comment: @Bergi This question is specifically about how to handle errors in fetch well, which is arguably less trivial than it should be. I therfore think this problem deserves its own question and should not be closed as a dup of a more general organization question.

Comment: @jib "*The problem is that when I parse it I lose the original response in the chain since I have to return `response.json()` because it's a promise*" is exactly what the canonical question is about

Comment: @Bergi The solution proposed here is different and in my opinion more clear though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my helper for sane `fetch` error handling, *fetchOk*:

```
let fetchOk = (...args) => fetch(...args)
  .then(res => res.ok ? res : res.json().then(data => {
    throw Object.assign(new Error(data.error_message), {name: res.statusText});
  }));
```

Which I then substitute for fetch.

```js
let fetchOk = (...args) => fetch(...args)
  .then(res => res.ok ? res : res.json().then(data => {
    throw Object.assign(new Error(data.error_message), {name: res.statusText});
  }));

fetchOk("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/blah")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(e => console.log(e)); // Bad Request: no method found with this name

var console = { log: msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>" };
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

It doesn't load the data unless there's an error, making it a direct replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I use the new async/await syntax, since that reads in a more intuitive way:

```
 async fetchData(request) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(request)
      const data = await response.json()

      // return the data if the response was ok
      if (response.ok) return { data }

      // otherwise return an error with the error data
      const error = new Error(response.statusText)
      if (data.errors) error.errors = data.errors

      throw error
    } catch (error) {
      return { error }
    }
  }
```

It makes it very easy to handle both the promise that `fetch` returns as well as the promise that `response.json()` returns.