# Small precision on async / await

Tags: javascript

Something escapes me about the result of using async / await

```
async function firstAsync() {
    let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => res("Now it's done!"), 1000)
    });
    let result = await promise;
    console.log(result);
}
firstAsync();
console.log('toto')
```

The execution of the preceding example displays in the console:

> toto
>
> Now it's done!

This does not correspond at all to what should look like synchronous execution.
In the case of synchronous execution the result should be

> Now it's done!
>
> toto

Did I miss something ??
Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: You haven't done anything that would cause `console.log('toto')` to wait until after the promise returned from `firstAsync();` has settled before running.

Comment: But it's _not_ synchronous. What makes you think it is? It's even in the name : `async function`.

Comment: `async` functions are *asynchronous*. Your code isn't waiting for the asynchronous process started by `firstAsync` to complete before doing the `console.log('toto')`, so the `console.log('toto')` happens before code that waits for the process to complete happens. `async` functions return promises. To wait for the promise to settle before doing something, you have to consume that promise. For instance: `await firstAsync(); console.log('toto');` or in a context where you can't use `await`: `firstAync().then(() => { console.log('toto'); }).catch(error => { /*...handle/report error...*/ });`

Comment: Try putting await in front of `firstAsync()`?

Comment: I wonder if there's a better dupetarget than the massive and very general [*"return the result of an asynchronous call"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) one...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842147/javascript-sync-wait-for-async-operation-sleep or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level maybe?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder perhaps I can suggest [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561573/what-guarantees-exist-in-asynchronous-javascript/66561926#66561926) that I wrote two days ago?

Comment: @yvan Coyaud try `firstAsync().then(() => console.log('toto'))` Notice how using `aync/await` just moved the problem outward. I advise you to write your async code with `then` and later refactor with `async/await` when you have it working. Often times you will prefer the version using `then`