# How to run fetch in Sync Way to block main thread?

Tags: javascript

Actually, due to learning purposes I want to send a HTTP request but in a Sync way in javascript.

How can I do it?

*Note: I want the main thread blocked during the request.*

Comment: async await ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make javascript fetch synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735669/how-to-make-javascript-fetch-synchronous)

Comment: @sojin async/await doesn't block the main thread!

Comment: As it shouldn't.

Comment: @Plagiatus None of them blocks the main thread!

Comment: You can't do this reliably, nor should you want to.

Comment: the linked answer answers this question, too. TLDR: **You can't make fetch synchronous.** You can use XMLHttpRequest instead to make a synchronous request.

Comment: @Plagiatus Yeah, you're right.
I could do it with `XHR` but it's not possible for `fetch`.

Comment: There is a library which mimics a sync fetch: `sync-fetch`; `const fetch = require('sync-fetch'); console.log('before fetch'); console.log(fetch('https://google.com').text()); console.log('hello, finished');`