# Multiple fetch() in Promise.all - which one failed?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

If I have multiple `fetch()` calls within a `Promise.all` block, when one fails, it all fails. That's cool, I need them all to resolve.

However, how can I find which one actually failed?

In the following code, the `catch error`tells me:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch`

which makes it impossible to construct an effective user error message should I choose to do so.

```
const goodUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
const badUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis77.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
Promise.all([
    fetch(goodUrl),
    fetch(badUrl), /* will fail */
    fetch(goodUrl)
]).then(([response1, response2, response3]) => {
    console.log(response1);
    console.log(response2);
    console.log(response3);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

[Here's a fiddle (a snippet didn't play nice)](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/wr6vj74a/2/)

I have looked for duplicates, [this is not one as the examples throw the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693382/using-fetch-api-with-promise-all)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just catch each of them individually and `throw` some custom errors like:

```
...
Promise.all([
    fetch(goodUrl).catch(err => {
        throw {url: goodUrl, err};
    }),
    fetch(badUrl).catch(err => {
       throw {url: badUrl, err};
    }),
    fetch(goodUrl).catch(err => {
       throw {url: goodUrl, err};
    })
])
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{url: badUrl, err:err}`?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel `{ err }` is [shorthand notation](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand) for `{ err : err }`

Comment: Ok, didn't know that and as I just tried it in the console it just returned `err` instead of `{url:'..', err:err}`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you make your own little wrapper around `fetch()` that throws a custom error that contains the desired information:

```
function myFetch(url) {
    return fetch(url).catch(function(err) {
       let myError = new Error("Fetch operation failed on " + url);
       myError.url = url;
       throw myError;
    });
}

const goodUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
const badUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis77.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
Promise.all([
    myFetch(goodUrl),
    myFetch(badUrl), /* will fail */
    myFetch(goodUrl)
]).then(([response1, response2, response3]) => {
    console.log(response1);
    console.log(response2);
    console.log(response3);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Working jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/1q34ah0g/